# How to add buttons at top of map fragment API v2 layout

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-button

I am trying to show maps in android using API v2.
I want UI some thing like this.But whenever **I try to add button in layout it does not reflect in output**
**I am able to get maps without buttons**.
**I need buttons to integrate with map like below** 
code for Mylayout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapActivity" >
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp">
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<RadioGroup 
android:id="@+id/radio_group_list_selector"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_weight="1"

>
<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/radioPopular"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:text="@string/Popular"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:button="@null"
android:background="@drawable/shape_radiobutton"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
android:textColor="@drawable/textcolor_radiobutton"

/>
<View
android:id="@+id/VerticalLine"
android:layout_width="1dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
android:background="#aaa"
            />
<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/radioAZ"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:text="@string/AZ"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:button="@null"
android:background="@drawable/shape_radiobutton2"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
android:textColor="@drawable/textcolor_radiobutton"

/>
 <View
android:id="@+id/VerticalLine"
android:layout_width="1dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
android:background="#aaa"
            />
<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/radioCategory"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:text="@string/Category"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:button="@null"
android:background="@drawable/shape_radiobutton2"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
android:textColor="@drawable/textcolor_radiobutton"

/>
<View
android:id="@+id/VerticalLine"
android:layout_width="1dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
android:background="#aaa"
/>

<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/radioNearBy"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:text="@string/NearBy"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:button="@null"
android:background="@drawable/shape_radiobutton3"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
android:textColor="@drawable/textcolor_radiobutton"
/>

</RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
<!-- For Horizontal Line-->
<View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="1dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
android:background="#aaa"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:scrollbars="vertical"  
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Maps with Button]

Comment: @JoxTraex: added the Layout code I tried in order to achieve the desired output

Comment: **FrameLayout** is the key!

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Maybe a simpler solution is to set an overlay in front of your map using `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and treating them as regular buttons in your activity. You should declare your layers in back to front order, e.g., map before buttons. I modified your layout, simplified it a little bit. Try the following layout and see if it works for you:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity" >

    <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"  
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <RadioGroup 
        android:id="@+id/radio_group_list_selector"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:padding="4dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioPopular"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/Popular"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_radiobutton"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor_radiobutton" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/VerticalLine"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#aaa" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioAZ"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/AZ"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_radiobutton2"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor_radiobutton" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/VerticalLine"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#aaa" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioCategory"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/Category"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_radiobutton2"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor_radiobutton" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/VerticalLine"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#aaa" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioNearBy"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/NearBy"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_radiobutton3"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor_radiobutton" />
    </RadioGroup>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: @de Almeida: Exactly what I wanted.Thanks Great Help Buddy.Hope one day I help you as you helped me

Comment: its hiding one gps location symbol(the one on which when we click we camera focus to our gps location) and somehow gps location(blue dot) is missing in map view..

Comment: @sandeep: MapView does not interact with your GPS. It is only a map. If you want to create a navigation functionality, you have to capture your GPS position yourself and create the buttons, markers and functionality. MapView will, at its best, provide some methods for zooming in and moving map, such as `animateCamera(CameraUpdate update)`. More info in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap

Comment: de Almeida : Thanks a lot for Info ! :) .Since I m new ,dont know stuff in detail.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get `Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix` on `xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: This answer is very useful, It saved a lot of my time!

Comment: Hi, I know its late. There have been some changes in the API, I guess. While running the above code, it showing "Didn't find class "com.google.android.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" error. I imported the package in the MapsActivity.java. But still I am unable to fix it. Your help required.

Comment: I was stuck on this for hours! Thank you.

Answer (score 67):

[image: Button Above The Map]

If this is what you want ...simply add button inside the Fragment.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.LocationChooser">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:text="Demo Button" 
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

</fragment>
```

Comment: this works for me! is there anything about this that's bad practice?

Comment: Add a closing tag of <fragment> would complete this example. Otherwise you get "Error parsing XML: no element found". Thank you for the example.

Comment: when im putting a button tag inside the map fragment, I am having a rendering problems in my xml design view and it's not showing my design view. How's that ?

Comment: @katwal-Dipak   What if we are adding fragment in java code and button in xml?

Comment: can you please post the java portion. How am i defining the `map` variable in java?

Comment: Thanks! But in you example you missing this code   android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#808080" 
android:alpha="0.5"

Comment: To use that button, you need to set an ID to call it from Java.class like this: android:id="@+id/button1"

Answer (score 3):

extending de Almeida's answer I am editing  code little bit here.
since previous code was hiding gps location icon I did following way which worked better.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

>

<RadioGroup 
    android:id="@+id/radio_group_list_selector"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:padding="4dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioPopular"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/Popular"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:button="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_radiobutton"
        android:textColor="@drawable/textcolor_radiobutton" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/VerticalLine"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioAZ"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/AZ"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:button="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_radiobutton2"
        android:textColor="@drawable/textcolor_radiobutton" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/VerticalLine"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioCategory"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/Category"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:button="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_radiobutton2"
        android:textColor="@drawable/textcolor_radiobutton" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/VerticalLine"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioNearBy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/NearBy"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:button="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_radiobutton3"
        android:textColor="@drawable/textcolor_radiobutton" />
</RadioGroup>

<fragment
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Comment: Hi, I know its late. There have been some changes in the API, I guess. While running the above code, it showing "Didn't find class "com.google.android.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" error. I imported the package in the MapsActivity.java. But still I am unable to fix it. Your help required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to change the button to Left side.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.zakasoft.mymap.MapsActivity" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="Send"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

</fragment>
```