# Set a textview on top of a Map Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to create this layout, but I am unable to set the Text Image on the fragment. My requirement to set the layout is as I show in the attached image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <!-- ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/atm" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Name of ATM -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <!-- Location -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: post the code that you have tried

Comment: @amalBit I have updated the code ..please check it

Comment: check this answer.. it covers your question i guess[. link.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14706956/2219600)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Put map fragment as **first one** (order matters!) in your `RelativeLayout` (so it will be on "bottom"). Then (at least I'd do that for simplicity) group all items you want in your overlay in another container (i.e. `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`), position that container on top of your view and you are mostly done.

Comment: Great answer! The key point is to put map fragment first of all

Comment: Great answer.This has helped me alot.