# How to add legend in mapv2 and customize it in google map v2 in android?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, legend

Hi I am creating android application, in which i have to show Custom legends on map(Google map v2). I have searched on google but did not find any useful information.My question is , Is it possible to add legends on googlemap v2. if Yes Please let me know how may i do this ??? Any tutorial or useful links will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Set a textview on top of a Map Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431927/set-a-textview-on-top-of-a-map-fragment)

or

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="152dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.71"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</fragment>
```