# TextBox over MapFragment Clickable

Tags: android, google-maps, textview

I followed this [url link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431927/set-a-textview-on-top-of-a-map-fragment)
I successfully did this but the text box is not responding to touch.
I want to write in this text box and get the location. I just need to know how to make the text box respond to my touch.
How can I do that?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="">


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:clickable="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you adding the onclicklistener to the view?

Comment: won't it just repond without java code?

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala textView does not respond without Java code. I guess you need to use EditText here, which will give you option to input some value

Comment: agree with @Arshad .

Comment: Ah. damn me.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:hint="Search Location Here" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:onClick="onMapSearch"
            android:text="Search" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.viralandroid.googlemapsandroidapi.MapsActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Text box on MapFragment..