# How I can customise zoom button and compass android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Currently I have integrated  google maps V2 in my app successfully. In the maps interface, zoom button and compass are standard. Now I want to customize the compass and zoom buttons or simply hide them.

Can I do this? If yes, how? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To hide them, call setZoomControlsEnabled(false) and setCompassEnabled(false) methods on your map.

Comment: and if i want to customise them ?

Comment: customise in what way? different look/function?

Comment: This question has someone adding buttons etc. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14694119/1898809

Comment: Breadbin i want to change the background of the zoom button it's possible or no ? and thanx

Comment: you would most likely need to hide the default buttons and create your own. Might not be worth the effort...