# Adding a button to Google Maps fragment layout

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to add  a button at the top left corner of the map.

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"


          />
```

I have tried putting the fragment inside a relative layout, but the app crashes.

I have also seen other proposals, but i am not able to make work any of them.

I only need to put a button on the map.

EDITED:

Text for the exception:

```
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria/com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria.Empresas_Mapa}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria.Empresas_Mapa.onCreate(Empresas_Mapa.java:47)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     ... 11 more
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4709)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
04-20 23:35:18.468: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: Please add the stack trace for the crash

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694119/how-to-add-buttons-at-top-of-map-fragment-api-v2-layout

Comment: Check out my answer it will work for you.

Comment: @Matt, logcat posted on the question

Answer (score 2):

I bet here is your problem:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment`

Try declaring SupportMapFragment in your xml instead of MapFragment. And also check that your Activity class extends FragmentActivity

Comment: Thank you, but already answered.